# Run Groovy script - Sending email

Tags: email, groovy, send

I am trying to write a groovy files that parse some data and send email.

I tried to import below packages for this purpose:

```
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*
```

And tried to run the groovy file as `./test.groovy` , but it shows the error "import command not found"

Is this the correct way to run the groovy script? Anyone please help me to write a groovy script that helps to email

Answer (score 2):

The `javax.mail` classes are not part of the JDK, so you need to explicitly include them. In a Groovy script, the easiest way to do this is with `@Grab`, e.g.

```
@Grab(group='javax.mail', module='mail', version='1.4.7')
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*

// the rest of your script goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send an email by using the Email-ext plugin as follows:

```
emailext body: '''African child
African child''', subject: 'African child', to: 'patrick@xxxx'
```

Note that this will only work within a proper job, not in Jenkins script interface