# Email notification from groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38656002/3317808) just talks about including packages.

In the below scripted pipeline code:

```
try{
    dir("${repo}") {
        git branch: "${branch}", 
            credentialsId: "${credentials}",
            url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}"
    }    
}catch(RuntimeException r){
    // send an email
}
```

---

How to send an email?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/

Comment: https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-sending-email-on-post-build-938b236545d2

Comment: @daggett jenkins reference you shared has declarative syntax. Am using scripted pipeline

Comment: scripted pipeline and declarative syntax??? what you are talking about? according to your logic `git` also belongs to declarative in your example...